# Does Cypress .trigger() and .type() actually trigger an actual keydown event?

Tags: vue.js, cypress

We have a small Vue 2 app managing a form and its submission.
In the Vue app, there is a method on the the input field for a credit card expiration date.

```
<input
     v-model="expDate"
     type="text"
     name="expirDate"
     placeholder="MMYY"
     @blur="checkExpDate"
     @keydown="appendSlash($event)"
/>
```

We have an appendSlash() method that checks each keydown and adds a slash after the first two digits are typed in:

```
appendSlash(event) {
      if (
        event.key === "Backspace" ||
        event.key === "Tab" ||
        (event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57)
      ) {
        if (
          this.expDate.length === 2 &&
          event.key !== "/" &&
          event.key !== "Backspace"
        ) {
          this.expDate += "/";
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
```

This works fine if we manually do this in the browser.  However, our QA person has tried to automate this via the following Cypress methods, but the slash never gets added.

```
cy.get('input').type('0925');
```

```
cy.get('input').type('09');
cy.wait(5000);
cy.get('input').type('25');
```

```
cy.get('input').trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 48 })
cy.wait(5000);
cy.get('input').trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 57 })
cy.wait(5000);
```

Does .trigger() and .type() provide a real keyboard event, or is our QA just using the Cypress API incorrectly?

(I understand there is a vue-cypress module available, but we can't use it yet in our infrastructure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard back from the QA person.

They ended up solving it using .clear() and .invoke().

```
cy.xpath('//input[@name="expirDate"]').clear().invoke('val', '05/25').trigger('input');
```

They said they had to clear the field first, then put in the number, and finally trigger an input event.  It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does according to the documentation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type#Events).

Also, this is the info you get when you click on the `type` action in the cypress UI and the action output gets printed to the console:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @PeaceAndQuiet.  I'll have to ask QA to put some console.log() in that method and see what the event code is coming back, because if Cypress generates genuine events, the method should work.